# JQuery: Selecting all data attributes where the key starts with x

Tags: jquery, html

How do you select all HTML5 data attributes in JQuery where the **key** start with company? I.e. company*.

I know it is possible to do this for the value. As you can see from my example, I'm trying to 'squeeze in' an extra data field in each data attribute after the underscore on which I would explode later.

```
<a data-company_1="CocaCola" data-company_2="Apple" data-company_3="Oracle"></a>
```

I'm trying to avoid usage of if ~key indexOf because I have a lot of data-* attributes for other purpose in this `<a>` element.

```
        $.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {

           if (~key.indexOf("company")) {
              var id = key.split('_')[1];
              //do something with both the key and value
           }
```

Comment: `I'm trying to avoid usage of if ~key indexOf` but why? To know if the attribute has `company` you need to loop it at any cost since you have multiple attribute with `company` as a substring.

Comment: For the solution for the value part you do not have to. "input[name^='news']" for example. .